# spaCy issue with 'Vocab' or 'StringStore'

Tags: python-3.x, spacy, rasa-nlu, rasa

I am training the Rasa NLU using spaCy for the pipeline, but when I try to train it I get this error from spaCy:

```
KeyError: "[E018] Can't retrieve string for hash '18446744072967274715'. This usually refers to an issue with the `Vocab` or `StringStore`."
```

I have python 3.7.3, spaCy version is 2.2.3, rasa version 1.6.1

Does someone knows how to fix this issue?

Comment: Please see this GitHub mega-thread regarding this issue: https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/3052.

Answer (score 0):

that's Sounds like a named mistake, I guess you applied a matcher for a text on another one, and the matcher_id became different, so that ist's getconfused.
to solve it make sure that you use the same matcher on the same text, like below:

## Perform standard imports, reset nlp , PhraseMatcher library

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
from spacy.matcher import PhraseMatcher
matcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab)
dd = 'refers to the economic policies  associated with supply-side economics, voodoo economics'
doc3 = nlp(dd) # convert string to spacy.tokens.doc.Doc
```

## First, create a list of match phrases:

```
phrase_list = ['voodoo economics', 'supply-side economics', 'free-market economics']
```

## Next, convert each phrase to a Doc object:

```
phrase_patterns = [nlp(text) for text in phrase_list]
```

## Pass each Doc object into matcher (note the use of the asterisk!):

```
matcher.add('VoodooEconomics', None, *phrase_patterns)
```

## Build a list of matches:

```
matches = matcher(doc3)
matches #(match_id, start, end)
```

## Viewing Matches:

```
for match_id, start, end in matches: # the matcher have to be the same one that we build on this text
     string_id = nlp.vocab.strings[match_id] 
     span = doc3[start:end]                   
     print(match_id, string_id, start, end, span.text)
```